# Extracting data from tkinter window. Geting a function similar to Matlab's inputdlg

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Hello to the community,

I learned some MATLAB coding skills a while ago and now I'm using python as a substitute. I would like to create a function similar to inputdlg from MATLAB.
I did a little bit of coding on python in order to create a function to import data from a tkinter window e.g.,the user gives two inputs (temperature 1 and 2) and the data gets saved to a variable. 
However, I'm getting problems when I  call the function in another script or when I paste the function code into another script. The window appears but it will not close nor will the python return from running. I assume that by mistake I made an infinite loop that is not getting solved. Can anyone help?

Best regards!

```
def input_dlg():

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class GetEntry():

    def __init__(self, master):


        self.master=master
        self.master.title('Input Dialog Box')
        self.entry_contents=None

        ## Set point entries

        # First point
        self.point1 = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.point1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.point1.focus_set()

        # Second point
        self.point2 = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.point2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.point2.focus_set()


        # labels
        ttk.Label(text='First Point').grid(row=0, column=0)
        ttk.Label(text='Second Point').grid(row=1, column=0)
        ttk.Button(master, text="Done", width=10,command=self.callback).grid(row=5, column=2)



    def callback(self):
        """ get the contents of the Entries and exit the prompt"""
        self.entry_contents=[self.point1.get(),self.point2.get()]
        self.master.quit()

master = tk.Tk()
GetPoints=GetEntry(master)
master.mainloop()

Points=GetPoints.entry_contents

return list(Points)
```

Comment: Use `self.master.destroy()` instead of `self.master.quit()`

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter has support for custom dialogs in the module `simpledialog` if you want to make your life simple.

`simpledialog` contains a class `Dialog` which is specifically made for you to inherit in your custom dialog. Check out the code in **simpledialog.py** in the catalog Python/Lib/tkinter

Before you start coding your own class, check that the dialog behaves as you want it to. Try the code below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import simpledialog

root = Tk()     # There must be a root
root.withdraw() # but don't show it

text = simpledialog.askstring('Dialog', 'What?') # Python waits here ... 
print(text)
```

Root window should not show, only the dialog. When the dialog pops up Python will wait until you close it and then resume execution of the rest of the code.